# How can I ensure that my laptop will be replaced under warranty?

Tags: laptop, laptop-repair, warranty

I know this is a controversial question but please hear me out. I bought a laptop from one of the major Computer companies in the UK. I bought a 3yr accidental warranty with it. Ever since I bought it, the Laptop has given me problems. I have sent it in the company to be repaired and add new hard drives 4 times already and yet each time something else breaks.

Every single time they say part of the problem is the Hard Drive and replace it. So every time I have to backup all my files, and reinstall all my programs with Windows.

I have just received my Laptop back from the company this week and before I wasted my time setting it all up again, I showed it to an IT Laptop specialist. He opened it and was appalled at the service. To quote his words, there are so many problems that it will break in another month or so, they have definitely not repaired things as they should under the warranty.

I nevertheless continued and set up the laptop again, one last time, to see if it would work. Yesterday, the Laptop switched off in the middle of my unsaved work 3 times. Today the Wireless connection continues to switch off until the laptop is restarted.

I have had enough. I want to send it in one last time totally irreparable so that  they will be forced to replace the whole computer including. New chip, fan, hard drive, wires, casing etc.

What then is the best way of destroying my laptop (albeit accidentally) making it totally irreparable and yet still look accidental?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wKhiVZUjPx4

Comment: in Portugal, its common that after 3 fixes/complaints by/at the store or manufacturer implies replacing the whole hardware free of cost.

Comment: You should not destroy it, because then they wan't be replacing it for free. Actually when you send a product more then 3 Times they give you a new product. So i would suggest you to keep on sending your laptop and ask them to replace it because you already send it 5 times. Just keep on doing it, there is no other way. If you open your laptop on your own you will loose the warranty!